# Am I Able To Save Remix.IDE Files To My Device?

Tags: solidity, remix, ide

I am a computer science student and for my coursework, I want to write a smart contract program. I discovered the Remix.IDE is a web-based IDE, not like previous IDEs I have used, such as IDLE for Python. I would like to code my project in Solidility preferably 0.6.3.

I was wondering is it possible to:

A) Get a downloaded version of this IDE where I can run my projects- one similar to Python's IDLE.

B) Save files from the Web Remix IDE to my laptop? If the answer is yes, how would I do that?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge I am very new to Ethereum and smart contracts.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

A) Yes, you can install a downloaded version of Remix IDE from https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide Although, I suggest to use the online version to avoid installation dependencies and save laptop storage. You have the option to choose any solidity compiler version on Remix online IDE only.

B) No, you cannot download Remix files. However, you can copy and paste the code in any text editor. Another option is to publish your files to your GitHub gist.
If you are worried about losing your solidity code, no worries, it stays on Remix even if you close the browser/laptop.

Comment: "You have the option to choose any solidity compiler version on Remix online IDE only." - So does this mean, that I cannot use Solidity at all on downloaded versions of remix IDE or I can only use certain versions of Solidity?

Comment: Yes, only a certain version. When you download the Remix IDE for offline usage, it will have the latest version of solidity with which it was packed. That means you cannot compile and test your code against older versions of solidity.

Answer (score 0):

You can install remix on your pc so you can run it offline.

Download remix from:

https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide